# Magento - Not able to display tier pricing in product view

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have a different price set for products based on customer group. I want to show both price's to the customer in case both of them apply in product list, view, related and upsell products.

I turned on template path hints to verify that prices for all views are being rendered from the same template file, which is as follows:

> /app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/catalog/product

I can see tier pricing correctly in product list, related and upsell products, but NOT for product view.

After debugging for a while I have narrowed down the problematic part of catalog/product/price.phtml file as follows:

```
<?php
    $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
    $_weeeHelper = $this->helper('weee');
    $_taxHelper  = $this->helper('tax');

    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_id = $_product->getId();
    echo 'Product Id: ' . $_id;
    $_weeeSeparator = '';
    $_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());
    echo 'Simple Price Tax: ' . $_simplePricesTax;
    $_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
    echo 'Minimal Price Value: ' . $_minimalPriceValue;
    //$_minimalPriceValue = 41;
    $_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $_simplePricesTax);
    echo 'Minimal Price: ' . $_minimalPrice;
    //$_minimalPrice = 41;
?>
```

I have echoed all prices fetched from models above, and only in case of product view page the $_product->getMinimalPrice() above does not return anything, while it appears correctly on list, related and upsell products.

I cannot think of any reason for this. There are a few lines different in catalog.xml but I don't think they have anything to do with this. Besides, there are a couple of commented lines in the above code, where I have hard-coded the minimalPrice and minimalPriceValue variables. After doing that the price starts appearing in product view also. The Product id for all views including product view is also appearing correctly, so the product IS loaded at that time.

We are using a custom template, and I see that in default we are not having this problem. I am using Magento 1.4.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you say that what you are trying to do works 100% with a stock theme?  If so then you really should look at the differences between your custom theme and the default.  Also, you might want to look at any changes the developer made in app/code/community and app/code/local that are customizations for the theme.  There could be some conflict.

But if you can't find a difference maybe I can give a few hints as to why you might be seeing this behavior.  Sometimes the same model (and block) objects have different data in them when you are viewing on the category list page vs the product view page.  The reason is that backend queries to the database are different.  I did some work with the tiering system before and I remember that when you are looking at the catalog page, the pricing data actually comes from some catalogindex_* tables rather than the catalog_product_entity_* tables.  If I remember correctly, there are two tables that it queries, something like catalogindex_price and catalogindex_minimal_price.  But then when you are at the product view page the pricing data comes from the standard catalog_product_entity_* and catalog_product_entity_tier_price tables. Anyway, that probably doesn't solve your problem, but it might get you pointed in the right direction.  Good luck.

Comment: This finally helped me to reach the solution. For product view the tier prices are being fetched and displayed through <template>/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml. For this to be called the following line should be a line in <template>/catalog/product/view.phtml
'<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>'